# i have a python list, using map function is omitting the first zero of the list

Tags: python, list, map-function

I have this code in python, when I print the last line, it is giving an output "11100101100". I'm expecting the output,"011100101100". Notice that the output starts with 1 and not 0. although the variable `gamma_sum_list` is a list containing 12 digits and its starts with 0. The function somehow deletes the first zero automatically. The following is the exact `gamma_sum_list`:

```
def convert(list)
   res = int("".join(map(str,list)))
   return res
print(convert(gamma_sum_list))
```

Input:

```
[0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]
```

Expected Output:

```
011100101100
```

Actual Output :

```
11100101100
```

Comment: please provide sample input output clearly

Comment: don't use `list` as a variable name, it is a built-in name

Comment: you convert it to an integer so the leading zeros are removed

Comment: Hi, Mattiss, I changed the name 'list', to 'x', its still giving the same output.

Comment: Hi Shivankgtm, I have added a bracket input

Comment: that was a suggestion to not use the name `list` because it is a built-in name so you shouldn't use it, not that it would solve the issue, but I have explained the issue in my other comment

Comment: Hint: what happens when you try `int('01')`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is caused by converting the result of the `join` operation to an integer. Integers do not have leading zeroes. If you remove the `int` function you'll get a string with the leading zero you're after.

```
gamma_sum_list = [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]

def convert(my_list):
res = "".join(map(str,my_list))
return res

print(convert(gamma_sum_list))
```

Output:

```
011100101100
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def convert(some_list):


   res = "".join(map(str,some_list))
   return res

gamma_sum_list = [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]


print(convert(gamma_sum_list))
```

or

```
conv = lambda x: ''.join(map(str, x))
print(conv(gamma_sum_list))
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider that:

```
>>> "".join(list(map(str, [0, 1])))
'01'
```

How would you convert `'01'` to an integer? Well, its just `1`.

```
>>> int("".join(list(map(str, [0, 1]))))
1
```

So you probably want to not convert the string to an `int`, just keep it as a `str`.